# Laravel route filter when *not* starts with?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Right now I've got

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', ['post']);
```

in my `routes.php` file to protect me against CSRF attacks. In `filters.php` I have:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() !== Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having now is that I'm integrating with a 3rd party service (Google Calendar API) and it POSTs back to my website, which of course trips the CSRF protection.

How do I disable that filter for a particular path prefix, say `/gapi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define **2 route groups** and apply **csrf** and apply **CSRF** filter to one of them. This way you can separate routes that need to have **CSRF** protection enabled from those, that don't need that.

This will work for you:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
  if (Request::method() == 'POST' && Session::token() !== Input::get('_token')) {
    throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
  }
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {
  // here define all routes that need CSRF protection enabled 
});

Route::group(array(), function() {
  // here define all routes that do not need CSRF protection
});
```

You can read more about how route grouping works in **Laravel 4.2** here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups

Comment: Can I still limit it to POST routes only? My route groups will get really hairy if I have to start separating them into separate groups based on HTTP method.

Comment: Not with route groups. But you can always check HTTP method inside the filter and do the check if the method is POST

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude routes beginning with a specific URL:

```
Route::whenRegex('#(?!gapi/)#A', 'csrf', ['post']);
```